# How to add nebular icons to an angular project?

Tags: angular, icons, nebular, ngx-admin

I'm trying to create a Webapp with Angular 7 and Nebular.

Therefore I used schematics to install Nebular:
`ng add @nebular/theme`

So I do have nebular-icons within my node_modules and included in my package.json as dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "nebular-icons": "^1.1.0",
    ...
  },
```

I also tried to add nebular-icons to styles in angular.json:

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss",
    "node_modules/nebular-icons/scss/nebular-icons.scss"
],
```

Now if I try to use an icon, it still won't show up. For example:

```
<nb-layout-header subheader>
    <nb-actions>
      <nb-action icon="nb-home"></nb-action>
      <nb-action icon="nb-search"></nb-action>
      <nb-action icon="nb-edit"></nb-action>
    </nb-actions>
</nb-layout-header>
```

Unfortunately, the icons don't show up. I can only see the lines ("|") that separate the icons of nb-actions, but not the icons themselves.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I tried to replicate the issue and ran into the same problem as you.

a little further search showed me that I had to [install some more dependencies](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues/1551), so after installing these, i got the following error:
 (check screenshot below)

[image]

The error simply states that we are unable to reach the ttf, woff, svg files which contain the actual font, so in my

So, in my **styles.css** file, i just inserted the CDN paths to these files...

```
@font-face{
font-family:nebular;
src:url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nebular-icons@1.1.0/fonts/nebular.eot?4ozerq");src:url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nebular-icons@1.1.0/fonts/nebular.eot?4ozerq#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nebular-icons@1.1.0/fonts/nebular.ttf?4ozerq") format("truetype"),url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nebular-icons@1.1.0/fonts/nebular.woff?4ozerq") format("woff"),url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nebular-icons@1.1.0/fonts/nebular.svg?4ozerq#nebular") format("svg");
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}
```

you can check the [complete demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkcrjv?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

Comment: Thanks for your support. I couldn't solve the problem so far. I also don't get any error messages in the console.

Comment: Did you go over the dependencies I added? Check angular.json and package.json files in the stackblitz that I added